# MySQL- Can any one please explain this query

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I want to understand the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary 
FROM employees a 
WHERE 3 >= (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) 
    FROM employees b 
    WHERE b.salary <= a.salary
) 
ORDER BY a.salary DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the inner SELECT (a correlated sub-query).  Such a query will be executed for each row in the outer query.  So what does it do?

Return the number of unique salaries that are less than or equal to the current employee's salary.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) 
FROM employees b 
WHERE b.salary <= a.salary
```

So, given that number for the current row of the outer select, what does that do?  Return the unique salaries (in order) where the number returned from the sub-query is less than or equal to 3.

```
SELECT DISTINCT salary 
FROM employees a 
WHERE 3 >= (some number)
ORDER BY a.salary DESC;
```

Putting it all together, we fetch:

Unique salaries in order where such a salary is one of the worst 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this query should return the 3 worst salaries!

Comment: Got it..Thank you :)